# Kubernetes - Prometheus Missing All NGINX Ingress Metrics?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-ingress

I have a DigitalOcean Kubernetes cluster. I have installed the NGINX Ingress Controller via Helm & also installed Prometheus & Grafana.

My ingresses are in the `default` namespace, my monitoring is in a `monitoring` namespace.

Here are the versions of the charts i have installed.

```
❯ helm list
NAME            REVISION    UPDATED                     STATUS      CHART                   APP VERSION NAMESPACE
grafana         1           Mon Oct  7 08:04:15 2019    DEPLOYED    grafana-3.8.18          6.3.5       monitoring
metrics-server  1           Thu Aug 29 09:07:21 2019    DEPLOYED    metrics-server-2.8.2    0.3.2       kube-system
nginx-ingress   1           Wed Aug 21 21:32:06 2019    DEPLOYED    nginx-ingress-1.17.1    0.25.1      default
prometheus      1           Mon Oct  7 09:24:21 2019    DEPLOYED    prometheus-9.1.2        2.11.1      monitoring
```

I'm trying to get some NGINX Metrics, so i can monitor in Grafana.

However, none of them appear in the Prometheus UI. I have tried adding the prometheus flags to all my ingresses, but still get nothing. e.g.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ****-ingress
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    enable-vts-status: "true"
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    prometheus.io/port: "10254"
```

I used the default [values.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/values.yaml) file for the nginx controller, but i did change to enable metrics:

```
  metrics:
    enabled: true
```

From what i read, it should work out of the box. So i have no idea what's going wrong.

[image: Prometheus Service Discovery]
[image: Prometheus Search Query]

One thing that does look suspicious, is that the service discovery doesn't seem to be monitoring any services, but i've never used Prometheus and i'm at a dead end with what to look for.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got there in the end. I have to create a prometheus job, to watch the NGINX Metrics server. I figured, that difference between my setup and all the examples online (even though i used the same helm charts) is that i have a separate NGINX metrics service, running on a different port. So OOB Prometheus was not configured to check it.

```
- job_name: nginx-ingress
      metrics_path: /metrics
      scrape_interval: 5s
      static_configs:
        - targets:
          - nginx-ingress-controller-metrics:9913
```

Added that to the prometheus configmap, and reloaded the config.

Comment: Hey Lloyd, could you please elaborate on "add that to the prometheus configmap and reloaded the config" ? I'm not sure how would I do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've deployed Prometheus from scratch. Nginx ingress metrics work only when you deployed Prometheus via [prometheus-operator](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use to find your selectors in the other namespaces also and have them come alive.  I was running into the same nginx ingress issue you were (same port etc).  I'm not sure which are the key lines so I added them all but it had mine come alive, and I think it's a bit more future proof.

```
  values:
    prometheus:
      prometheusSpec:
        # Use all prometheus rules on the cluster
        ruleNamespaceSelector:
          any: true
        ruleSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false

        # Use all service monitors on the cluster
        serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector:
          any: true
        serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false
```